# How do I vertically align div text inside of a td cell?

Tags: html, html-table

Here is a 3x3 table:

```
<html>
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<style>
div.table_div {overflow:scroll;width:378px;height:117px;position:relative;}
table.TheTable {width:361px;height:100px;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000;}
td.TheTableColumnCell {font-size:16px;line-height:14px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;border:1px solid #000000;}
</style>
<div class="table_div" id="table_div">
<table class="TheTable">
<tr id='firstTr'>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">
<div onclick="alert('1');" style="position:absolute;font-size:16px;line-height:14px;background-color:#FFFF00;left:0px;top:4px;width:60px;height:24px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Event: 1</div>
<div onclick="alert('2');" style="position:absolute;font-size:16px;line-height:14px;background-color:#FFFF00;left:90px;top:4px;width:30px;height:24px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Event: 2</div>
<div onclick="alert('3');" style="position:absolute;font-size:16px;line-height:14px;background-color:#FFFF00;left:150px;top:4px;width:210px;height:24px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Event: 3</div>
&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">I'm</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">Vertically</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">Aligned Middle!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you cut-and-paste that code into an html file and open it in your browser, you will see that the div's act as an overlay onto my grid.  This is sort-of like a Scheduling control (the grid represents each hour block).

The thing that's driving me crazy is that the I can't get the text inside the div tags to become vertically aligned in the middle.  The actual td tags, no problem.  But the div tags inside the td tag - nope!

I've read and tried everything here: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

I've tried (as a style for the div): padding, margins, line-heights, etc.

EDIT:  I think there is some confusion on the intent of this grid.  The reason I use the div tags is to overlay "the yellow bar" over the grid.  That means there could be multiple "yellow bars" inside of one td cell or it can span multiple cells.  For example, my original html (assuming the first column is 12:00 AM) has three events in that first row.  Event 1: 12:00 AM - 12:30 AM.  Event 2: 12:45 - 1:00 AM (both in the same cell).  Event 3: 1:15 AM - 3:00 AM (and it has overlapped two cells).  Stuff like that.  That's why the div tags.

[image: Schedule Control]

Comment: Have you tried displaying the div tags as table cells? display: table-cell;

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NytYh/

Comment: re: (display:table-cell); Yes.  I did try that.  Good suggestion though, I thought that might work too!!

Comment: Could you clarify: are you having trouble getting the yellow divs (themselves, the yellow background) vertically centered within the cells, or the text inside the divs vertically centered within the divs? If the latter, see my answer.

Comment: the text within the divs (not the divs themselves).  Let me go look at your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a single line in the div, try setting the line-height of the container to the same as the height of the container.

```
<div onclick="alert('1');" style="position:absolute;font-size:16px;line-height:24px;background-color:#FFFF00;left:0px;top:4px;width:60px;height:24px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Event: 1</div>
```

Comment: line-height equal to the height of the div worked.  Or it seems to work.  Thanks!  The example code I gave simulates a td cell height of 32px.  And it looks centered (and it looks centered for cell height's greater than 32).  What's strange is when I chose 16 as a td cell height, it doesn't really look vertically centered (I think).  But I could be nit-picking here.  You are in the running and will most likely get the check-mark.  I just want to see what other answers come.  But, thanks again!  I really appreciate it.  I'll up-vote for now.

Comment: @JustLooking FWIW, this is described as "Method 2" in the [document you claimed to have "tried everything" from](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html). ;)

Comment: @Phrogz, I know! :)  Though, I only chose a line-height up to the font-size, not over.  I'm not the most HTML'y guy in the world.  C++/C# programmer here.

Comment: @Matt C.  You were quick, and I've went with your solution.  So, green check-mark for you!  (And extra special thanks to Phrogz and TerryR - good stuff).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dramatically cleaned up version of your code with what I think is the answer you're looking for.

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/FXFF8/24/

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  And clean looking.  But, that dynamically changes what I'm trying to do.  Open up your outlook, create multiple appointments (within the same hour), and then look at the Schedule control.  Each td cell (for me) represents an 'hour'.  The div tags represent events\appointments.  There could be multiple tags within a cell.  My original html (that had two events in cell 1,1) was changed with your new html.  The 2nd event is now in row 1, column 2.  Thank you for the effort though.

Comment: @Phorgz, can I ask how that was a horror?  I mean, yes, I could clean it up using his version, but it drastically changed what I'm trying to do.  So it broke my original intent.

Comment: @JustLooking I previously revised my comment to remove the word 'horror'. That was inappropriately harsh. However, since you asked, your original markup [mixes style in the markup](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle), mixes code logic with markup, and [uses superfluous CSS classes](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#contextualselectors). Although TerryR's changes ended up not being what you needed for this question, the result was significantly less HTML and CSS; this is something you should strive for in your end result.

Comment: @Phorgz; Oooh!  Awesome advice.  I like it.  Especially the superfluous CSS class advice.  Although, forgive me for a second for the div tags.  I'm still in development, so I haven't moved it's styles to the style tag yet.

Comment: Updated my answer to not break your original code, while remaining clean.  Ideally the placements and widths would be done programmatically, but you get the idea.

Comment: @TerryR.  I really appreciate the effort.  I just up-voted you.  Thanks.  (I'll digest what you did tomorrow - no more code for tonight!)

Answer (score 1):

adding the event to the "TD" instead of div's wouldn't work for you?

```
    <html>
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<style>
div.table_div {overflow:scroll;width:378px;height:117px;position:relative;}
table.TheTable {width:361px;height:100px;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000;}
td.TheTableColumnCell {font-size:16px;line-height:14px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;border:1px solid #000000;}

</style>
<div class="table_div" id="table_div">
<table class="TheTable">
<tr id='firstTr'>
    <td class="TheTableColumnCell">
        <span onclick="alert('1');" style="font-size:16px;line-height:14px;background-color:#FFFF00;left:0px;top:4px;width:60px;height:24px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Event: 1</span>
    </td>   
    <td class="TheTableColumnCell">
        <span onclick="alert('2');" style="font-size:16px;line-height:14px;background-color:#FFFF00;left:90px;top:4px;width:30px;height:24px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Event: 2</span>
    </td>
    <td class="TheTableColumnCell">
        <span onclick="alert('3');" style="font-size:16px;line-height:14px;background-color:#FFFF00;left:150px;top:4px;width:210px;height:24px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">Event: 3</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">I'm</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">Vertically</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">Aligned Middle!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what I'm trying to do.  There could be multiple events (and thus onclick's) inside of one cell.  Thank you for the effort though.

Comment: oh ok but question should each div be inside a td or that part is not important to you?

Comment: If I can get that overlay (the yellow), I'll try any tag and it's placement.

Comment: try that i used spans and took out the position and put each span inside its own td.

Comment: Hey Andres, I up-voted you.  I really appreciate your time and effort.  Thanks.  (I went with Matt C's and Phrogz line-height solution).

Answer (score 1):

The position:absolute takes your divs out of the flow of the table, and makes them ignore the standard vertical-align.

You might be able to fixed it by using spans instead of divs, and using position:relative instead of absolute.

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3s4VE/

Comment: I really hope an up-vote gets you some points (I'm not entirely sure of the stackoverflow rules on how to get reputation).  I went with the line-height solution, but will definitely keep the span stuff in the back of my mind.  Thanks a lot for your input, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you are asking how to get the content of the divs vertically centered within the divs.*

Set the `line-height` to be the same as the `height`. Right now you have `line-height:14px; height:24px`.

Here's what it looks like if you set `line-height:24px`:  http://jsfiddle.net/NytYh/1/

[image]

Comment: That's what Matt C suggested.  And thanks.  Would still like your opinion on what causes this to be a horror.  I'm definitely interested in cleaner-code.  The guy you up-voted actually broke my intent.  So I can't clean it up to the extent that he did.  You get an up-vote for helping, though.  Thanks!!

Comment: @JustLooking You're welcome. As for what made me call the current code a 'horror/mess', I answered in my other comment. Here's how I would clean up your particular markup: http://jsfiddle.net/NytYh/2/ Best of luck in your ongoing CSS/HTML endeavors!

Comment: Just got home.  Really nice.  Thanks.  Like I mentioned, it's probably been at least 10 years since I've touched HTML.  You've definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `vertical-align:text-top; text-align:center`

http://jsfiddle.net/UxZr3/2/

Comment: I actually want (for the div and any td's - as this is the default for the td's): vertical-align:middle; text-align: left;  vertical-align:middle will do nothing to the div text.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that I understood. rs.

you can try this code:

```
<td align="center" valign="middle">
```

The `align` define the horizontal alignement and the Valign define vertical one.

got it?

regards!

Comment: Isn't valign deprecated?  Regardless, applying these properties to the td tag doesn't help.  It's the div text I'm concerned about.  That's what makes this one tricky.  Vertically aligning div text inside of a td cell (the td cell, already, by default, does what I want: vertically-aligned to the middle, horizontally-aligned to the left)

Comment: valign="middle" is the default value, so this won't make any difference